# Vanilla image for sahara cluster

Tags: hadoop, centos, cloud, centos7, openstack

I'm trying to install an image for sahara cluster. But the documentation is a little restrictive. I didn't find the qcow2 image adapted to sahara. the mirrors that exist now are no longer up to date.Therefore, I tried to follow this doc [Building Images for Vanilla Plugin](https://docs.openstack.org/sahara/queens/user/vanilla-imagebuilder.html)

In summary, I followed these steps:

1. Clone repository
   “https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/sahara-image-elements”
   locally.
2. Use tox to build images.
   `tox -e venv -- sahara-image-create -u`

The following error is throwing up

```
INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.blockdevice [-] State already cleaned - no way to do anything here
ERROR: InvocationError: '/opt/stack/sahara-image-elements/.tox/venv/bin/sahara-image-create'
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary ________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   venv: commands failed
```

I am using centos7 and openstack queens.
I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tox -e venv -- sahara-image-create -p vanilla -v 2.7.1 -i centos7
```

Comment: Hi , could you tell me did it work in your openstack ? I am using devstack , however , this image cann't boot as a cluster or a instance.Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Instance or cluster ? Try sahara-image-elements pike, I can boot it as a instance , However ,not working as a cluster ,perhaps my virtual server can not provides enough performance to boot it.
Unfortunately, mirantis no longer provides sahara images.

Comment: By the way , I am on devstack queens.

Comment: Now It can boot as a cluster , devstack queens and sahara-image-create pike . I use centos with root user.

Comment: You can try ubuntu,tox -e venv -- sahara-image-create -p vanilla -v 2.7.1 -i  ubuntu